# Php not establishing connection with sql server

Tags: php, database, freetds

I've successfully setup freetds and am able to get a prompt of 1> and also see the trace in sql profiler when i run this command in terminal:

```
tsql -S <server> -U <user> -P <pass>
```

But when I run my php code i get an error as well as no log in sql profiler:

```
mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: myserver in /var/www/myfolder/test/index.php on line 7
```

php code is fairly simple but here it is:

```
<?php

$server = "myserver";
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'password';

$conn = mssql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
mssql_select_db('mydb', $conn);
```

Checked phpinfo() and definitely have the mssql driver configured.

Any assistance is appreciated.